# Wordpress custom meta box for one page only

Tags: wordpress, meta-boxes

everyone!
I believe similar question have been asked already, but I had not found working solution.
The problem: I need a metabox for one exact page only.
The code I use to add a metabox is pretty simple:

```
function custom_meta_boxes(){
    add_meta_box('custom_meta_1', 'About Us Main field','custom_meta_boxes_render', 
        'page','normal','high','');
}
```

If you look on the 4th parameter -  'page', this puts metabox on every page, so that I see it and can use it for every page I created when editing it. And I need to see it on about us page only (for example).
I`ve seen in some tutorials that instead of 'page' you can use an ID or a slug of page, but that did not work for me.
Therefore, I really need your help/advice on that.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it like this:

```
<?php 

function custom_meta_boxes(){
  global $post;
  $postSlug = isset($post->slug) ? $post->slug : '';

  if ($post->slug === 'about-us') {
    add_meta_box(
      'custom_meta_1', 
      'About Us Main field',
      'custom_meta_boxes_render', 
      'page',
      'normal',
      'high',
      ''
    );
  }
}
```

And change about-us slug for that you want to add meta box.